# tcpclient - web client to get content in c

Tags: c, redirect, tcp, tcpclient

So here's the code I have to download content from a website, say, wiki

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
void error(char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", msg, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int d_sock;
    char buf[255];
    char rec[256];
    int bytesRcvd;
    int c, result;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    // get ip from list of domains and puts it onto heap called naming resource
    getaddrinfo("en.wikipedia.org", "80", &hints, &res);

    /*Creating socket */
    d_sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (d_sock == -1)
        error("Can't open socket");

    /*Connecting socket */
    c = connect(d_sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    if (c == -1)
        error("Can't connect to socket");

    /* Sending GET */
    sprintf(buf, "GET /wiki/%s http/1.1\r\n", argv[1]);
    result = send(d_sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    if (result == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "Error talking to the server",
    strerror(errno));

    /* Sending Host and blank line */
    memset(buf, 0, 255);
    strcpy(buf, "Host: en.wikipedia.org\r\n\r\n");
    result = send(d_sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
    if (result == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", "Error talking to the server",
    strerror(errno));

    /*Receiving the page information */
    bytesRcvd = recv(d_sock, rec, 255, 0);
    while (bytesRcvd) {
        if (bytesRcvd == -1)
            error("Can't read from server");
        rec[bytesRcvd] = '\0';
        printf("%s", rec);
        bytesRcvd = recv(d_sock, rec, 255, 0);
    }

    /*Closing socket */
    close(d_sock);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that the output

> HTTP/1.1 301 TLS Redirect 
>   Server: Varnish
>   Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/apples
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes
>   Date: Sat, 05 Dec 2015 06:46:13 GMT
>   ...

What happened and why is it being redirected? My course uses head first c book, and I even ran the example and it also gets redirected, but their snippets showed it successfully got the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wikipedia seems to redirect all http requests now to https, that's why you are getting this http redierect, maybe you should consider trying your code with another website that still uses http(maybe stackoverflow for example)

Comment: is there not a way to get a https? I tried changing sprintf(buf, "GET /wiki/%s http/1.1\r\n", argv[1]); to https for example

Comment: in order to use ssl you have to include a library that actually does the encryption (openssl for example) and I think that's beyond your course, that's why I advised you to switch to another website.

Comment: ah ok, that's understandable. thank you for your help!